# 404 Page Not Showing

Tags: 404-page

This probably has a very simple answer but cannot seem to get it working.

I have a 404.html template in craft/templates and it works fine within a section (such as https://shanehudson.net/articles/dfs) but not at all for non-existant pages in the root (such as https://shanehudson.net/404). Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? :)

Comment: It shows the _layout template correctly but with no content.

Comment: Do you have any routes defined that could be triggering? Can you check in chrome dev tools or similar, do the page return a HTTP 404 status, or a HTTP 200 (or something else)? You don't have any rewrite rules in your .htaccess that could cause this? Have you tried removing or running a minimal .htaccess file to see if you get the same response?

Comment: +1 for @AndréElvan's comment. I'd guess either a custom route or .htaccess rule.

Comment: Ah I tried and you are right about the dynamic urls. I need the entry types to be root pages. Such as https://shanehudson.net/articles, but if the slug for entry type doesn't exist, it should 404.

Comment: @ShaneHudson Can you update your question with more details about that? (e.g. a screenshot of your Route, and the contents of the template that the route points to)