# 404 error page not loading

Tags: 404-page

I found this question "[404 Page Not Showing](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/404-page-not-showing)" asked 3 years ago that the person who asked figured it out but didn't really expand on how they did.

I have basically the same issue, craft doesn't load the 404 error ever, it simply loads the template with nothing.
https://footwearoutfitters.net/123

I haven't edited any .htaccess files

Routes is left unmodified, both in the CP and the file itself.

I'm wondering if I setup my entries incorrectly for the URI, anyone have ideas or think of somewhere else I could give info on to help this along?

Here is my .htaccess folder in the public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using Apache? If you’re using Nginx then the .htaccess files are useless.

Comment: That's good to know, but yes, it's Apache. I have another site hosted on this same server and it works just fine with the 404 requests

Comment: Cool. Do you have anything in your `404.html` template?

Comment: Perhaps worth your time to take a peek at this article as well -> https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#handling-exceptions-on-the-frontend

Comment: I do have a 404.html, I haven't yet changed it from what craft put in. I will take a look at that article and update, thanks Jalen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my issue was very simple to solve once I paid better attention. The 404 was loading perfectly fine the whole time, my problem was that in my 404 file I had it as {% block content %} and not {% block main %} as I had specified in my layout.